# Test Driven Development in OOP, setting object state without using the public interface

Tags: oop, unit-testing

Suppose I was writing a clone of the game 2048 (http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) and I want to write a test to verify that "the right thing" happens when the game is "won". Suppose that my game state is encapsulated in a class and that the state itself is private.

I suppose that I could write code to play the game, evaluate through the public interface when I'm about to win and then make the winning move; however, this seems like overkill. I would instead like to set a game state, make the winning move and verify that the object behaves as expected.

What is the recommended way of designing such a test? My current thought is that the test should either be a public member function of the class or that the test infrastructure should be friended by the class. Both of these seem distasteful.

Edit: In response to the first question: I'm assuming in this example that I don't have a method to set the game state and that there's no reason to write one; therefore it would be adding additional functionality just to write a test... ...one that then requires another member function to test, a get game state function. So then I'm writing at least two more public methods and test just to write this one test. Worse, these are methods that essentially break encapsulation such that if the internal details change I have to change these two methods and their tests for no other reason than to have a test. This seems more distasteful than friending a test function.

Comment: If you would like to set a game state, then make it possible to set a game state. Add a constructor to the Game that sets it to a given state instead of setting it to its initial state. What's the problem? Might even be useful, not just for tests, to be able to save the game state and restore it later. Making your code testable is not a bad thing.

Comment: If you don't want to add such a constructor, then make the game state package private and put your test in the same package. Or use reflection to access the private game state. You'll need to set the state in one way or another.

Comment: @JBNizet I think your comments here are warranting an answer in themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remember that Test-Driven Development is a [*design*-oriented methodology](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/04/its-not-tdd-its-design-by-example.html). The primary goal of the tests is to influence the design of the SUT and its collaborators; everything else is just along for the ride.

Second, TDD emphasizes small steps. In his book, [Test-Driven Development: By Example](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321146530), Kent Beck says:

> *If you have to spend a hundred lines creating the objects for one single assertion, then something is wrong. Your objects are too big and need to be split.* (p. 194)

This means you should listen to your intuition about writing the code necessary to win the game being overkill.

You also said:

> I would instead like to set a game state, make the winning move and verify that the object behaves as expected.

**Which is *exactly* what you should do.**

Why? Because you're testing end-game scenarios. Most/all of the details that led to the end-game are irrelevant - you just want to make sure the program does "the right thing... when the game is won." As such, these are the only details that are relevant to your tests.

So what are these details that are relevant to your tests? To figure them out, it helps to discuss things with [a colleague](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

---

Q: How does the test configure the system to indicate the game has been won - *without actually playing the game*?

A: Tell something that the game has been won.

---

Q: What object would the test tell that the game has been won?

A: I don't know. But to keep things simple, let's say it's some object serving the role of "Referee".

---

By asking these questions, we've teased out some details of the design. Specifically, we've identified a role which can be represented in OOP [by an interface](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html).

What might this "Referee" role look like? Perhaps:

(pseudocode)

```
begin interface Referee
    method GameHasBeenWon returns boolean
end interface
```

The presence of an interface establishes [a seam in the design](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=359417&seqNum=2), which allows tests to use test-doubles in place of production objects. Not only that, it allows the implementation of this functionality to change (e.g., a rule change affecting how a game is determined to be "won") without having to modify any of the surrounding code.

This ties in directly with something else you mentioned:

> I'm assuming in this example that I don't have a method to set the game state and that there's no reason to write one; therefore it would be adding additional functionality just to write a test...

**A test is a consumer of your code.** If it is difficult for a test to interact with your code, then it will be even more difficult for production code (having many more constraints) to interact with it. This is what is meant by ["Listening to your tests"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321503627).

Note that there are a lot of possible designs that can fall out of TDD. Every developer is going to have their own preferences which will influence the look and feel of the architecture. The main takeaway is that TDD helps break your program up into many small pieces, which is one of the [core tenets of object oriented design](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html).